# AngularJS issue with allows only numbers to be typed into a textbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want user to allows only numbers to be typed into a textbox.
For this I am using below code :

```
.directive('digitOnly', [function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            digitOnly: '=?'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            if (scope.digitOnly || scope.digitOnly == undefined) {
                modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
                    if (inputValue == undefined) return '';
                    if (attrs.digitOnly == "false") {
                        return inputValue;
                    } else {
                        var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                        if (transformedInput != inputValue) {
                            modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                            modelCtrl.$render();
                        }
                        return transformedInput;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
}])
```

My input textbox code is given below :

```
<input type="text" name="sidNo" class="form-input" placeholder="Enter 5-6 digits"
ng-minlength="5" maxlength="6" ng-model="profInfo.sidNo" required digit-only
ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/">
```

It is working fine when I type anything. It restrict me to type except numbers.

But the problem is that when my ng-model value profInfo.sidNo comes from backend like `AASS001` that is showing me on textbox as invalid input error message that is correct but when I remove this value from backspace button it remove all value on single key press of backspace and input two Zeros like `00`

So please help me to fix this.

I am using AngularJS.

Comment: What exactly do you want fixed? The input does what it needs to, it removes all the invalid characters. Are you asking how to make the invalid characters stay, entirely defeating the purpose of the directive?

Comment: @GiovaniVercauteren I want to empty textbox value if there is any invalid character find only if when I copy paste some alphanumeric text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, @giovani-vercauteren is right, if you allow invalid characters, then is no point of using angular directive.
But the below hack can fulfill your requirement. I hope

```
var thisApp = angular.module('thisApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

thisApp.controller('MyCtrl',['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.btnClick= function(){
    $scope.sidNo='7AASS001';
    }
}]
);

thisApp.directive('digitOnly', [function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            digitOnly: '=?'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
        scope.isBackspacePressed=false;
        element.bind('keydown', function (e, inputs) {

            var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
            var val = element[0].value;

            var current = document.activeElement;
         //Enter all Charcodes u want where u want to prevent keypress
            if (code === 8 || code === 46) {
            scope.isBackspacePressed=true;
                }
        })
            if (scope.digitOnly || scope.digitOnly == undefined) {

                modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
                console.log(scope.isBackspacePressed)
                if(scope.isBackspacePressed)  {scope.isBackspacePressed=false; return inputValue;}
                    if (inputValue == undefined) return '';
                    if (attrs.digitOnly == "false") {
                        return inputValue;
                    } else {
                        var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                        if (transformedInput != inputValue) {
                            modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                            modelCtrl.$render();
                        }
                        return transformedInput;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
}])
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zinduyaar/z4m6kxfa/3/)

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use the number like @mpdev7 said, but to use ng-pattern in conjunction with it to prevent invalid characters:

```
<input type="number" ... etc />
```

Then you'd create a constant for your Regex like this one for example:

```
.constant('allowedSpecialCharactersRegex',
  /^[ a-zA-Z0-9!\"#\$£\%\&'\(\)\*\+\,\-\.\/\:\;\<\=\>\?@\[\\\]\^_\`\{\|\}~]*$/)
```

Then alter your template accordingly (note 'vm' assuming you have your Angular set up like that):

```
<input type="number" ... ng-pattern="vm.allowedSpecialCharactersRegex" />
```

Alter the pattern obviously, to remove chars you don't want.

Comment: I want to blank input textbox if there is any one character except digits only if when I copy paste some alphanumeric text.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for typing  only number in input it's use the input type="number", it is not what you are looking for?

input like this

```
<input type="number" name="sidNo" class="form-input" placeholder="Enter 5-6 digits"
ng-minlength="5" maxlength="6" ng-model="profInfo.sidNo" required">
```

Comment: This method allows the user to enter invalid characters, but it will not validate correctly. The directive OP made doesn't even allow the user to enter the invalid characters, they immediately get removed.